# Generate compilable code with clang ast-print and fsyntax-only

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

Running `clang++ -Xclang -ast-print -fsyntax-only -std=c++17 main.cpp` where the content of main.cpp is the following:

```
int main() {
  int res = 0;
  for (auto i = 0, j = 5; i > 0; ++i, j--) {
    res += i;
    res += j;
  }
  return res;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
int main() {
    int res = 0;
    for (auto i = 0, auto j = 5; i > 0; ++i , j--) {
        res += i;
        res += j;
    }
    return res;
}
```

This makes the for loop invalid because of the 1st statement "auto i = 0, auto j = 5" instead of "auto i = 0, j = 5". If instead of auto I use int, then i get "int i = 0, j = 5" and it's valid.

Is this a bug and is there any way I can tell clang to preprocess the file completely (-fsyntax-only) and generate code that can be compiled?

Comment: What about actually preprocessing? `cpp -std=c++17 -x c++ source.cpp`? Or `g++ -E ...` and `clang++ -E` ...?. Printing the ast doesn't say "print valid C++". It just prints a human-readable version of the AST

Comment: Also, out on a limb: https://cppinsights.io/s/c158d278 and https://godbolt.org/z/iHF8Gk (I'm guessing what you are trying to solve)

Comment: I am doing "clang++ -E x.cpp" at the moment.
However, that only expands macros and other directives. With this I also wanted to generate template instantiations. I use cppinsights and godbolt, but they are using libtooling exclusively. They don't just invoke a compiler command..
In cppinsights this works really good: https://cppinsights.io/s/f47c4865

Comment: I didn't think print-ast would give  you instantiations in the first place (it sort of conflicts with the idea of "syntax only" right?). TIL. Why does it matter that "they don't just invoke a compiler command"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to get the template instantiations, so then I can parse the code with llvm/clang, make some transformations to all functions (including template specializations retrieved in the 1st step) and then save/compile. BTW, that syntax-only is kind of confusing, but you can try it on the code that I shared at cppinsights with this command.